# Where does System.err.println output go in Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss

I have a class in a WAR that I know prints some System.err.println output - where will this output end up?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss redirects System.out and System.err to the console and to the log files in jboss/server/(serverinstance - generally default)/log/server.log.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JBoss expert, but I've used it a little bit.  Our .war would output the logs (both stdout and stderr) to the directory jboss/server/(servername)/log .  Do you have this directory?