# Can't see sysout statements in JBoss AS 5.0.0

Tags: logging, jboss5.x

All,
I have put some `System.out.println()` statements in a web application's servlet `init()`, doGet and doPost methods.

I have deployed the application on JBoss AS 5.0.0.

I also tried creating a static logger object and used the error level to log the same debug statements above.

NOTE: I did not use a `log4j.properties` (or xml) configuration file in my web application itself. I assume JBoss has already setup log4j.

I want to know where to see the logs/my debug statements? I have seen the files under `JBoss5.0.0_Install_Dir\server\default\log` folder on my windows machine so far.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1396353/331246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all logs from `System.out` and `System.err` are redirected to console and to the log file `server.log`. You should find there your messages.

On console JBoss displays only logs with priority `INFO` or higher. But in the `server.log` file you should find all logs from `DEBUG` priority (or higher).

You can configure logging subsystem just by edit `conf/jboss-log4j.xml` (in your current profile). These is the log4j configuration file.